# FHIR resource that includes patient income and household members

Tags: hl7-fhir

Patient income and household members seem to be included in a number of EMR's (e.g. Epic, OpenEMR), but I can't find the FHIR resource that includes these two parameters.

Is anything defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those would be captured as Observations.  They're point-in-time (and often reported) assertions.  You might find the LOINC codes 77244-2 and 86639-2 helpful.